# october cms (laravel) where query

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have a some problem with filter query. I need to do somethink like

`select painting from artist_painting where type=$_GET['type'] AND material=$_GET['material'] and artist_slug =$_GET['artist_slug'] ORDER BY painting DESC`

I have a pivot table artist_painting and artist. 'artist_slug' is in the 'artist' table

I do

```
$this['painting'] = Painting::whereHas('artist', function($q)
    {
         $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
    })->get();
```

but I do not know what to do next. 
How can i do query in php code?

Comment: Have you defined relationships between Models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and dirty:

```
Painting::where('type',input("type"))
->where('material',input("material"))
->whereHas('artist', function($q)
    {
         $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $this->param('slug'));
    })->get();
```

The explanation:

When you initialize a query a query builder instance is returned. Basically all methods on the query builder return the same instance so you can daisy chain them into one query.
But you can also just work on the query builder.

```
$query = Painting::where('type',input("type"));
```

or:

```
$query = $model->newQuery()// Where model is an intance of painting, for example new Painting();
```

Then you can just work on the query builder instance, pass it to other methods that might to do things.

```
function getPaintings($type, $material, $slug) 
{
     $query = Painting::where('type',$type);    
     $query->where('material', $material);
     $this->findArtistBySlug($query, $slug);
     return $query->get()
}

function findArtistBySlug($query, $slug) 
{
    $query->whereHas('artist', function($q) use ($slug)
    {
         $q->where('artist_slug', '=', $slug);
    });
    $query->with(['artist']);
}
```

You might want to read https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query
and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem from the Artist's point of view:

```
$artist = Artists::where('artist_slug', $this->param('slug'))->with('paintings')->first();
```

All the paintings of the artist can be accessed by using `$artist->paintings`, which will be a `Collection`.